# How do I avoid URL redirect when using SSLRequireSSL + ErrorDocument

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, .htaccess

Ok, so I have an Apache host I'm working on (shared host) who has this in their root `.htaccess` file.:

```
Options -Indexes

SSLOptions +StrictRequire

ErrorDocument 401 "<!DOCTYPE html><html lang='en'> ... "
ErrorDocument 403 "<!DOCTYPE html><html lang='en'> ... "

SSLRequireSSL
```

So when a user tries to connect without SSL, they are prompted with the custom `403` html listed in the file. This occurs while keeping their old URL in the address bar so they can just add the `https` quickly.

However, for error page improvements, it is desired to load a `php` file from `./error` and use that file in the definition for `ErrorDocument`. Now this is the kicker, if one just specifies the document directly...

```
ErrorDocument 403 /error/script.php
```

They will get another `403` or `Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.` since the connection to the file is not under SSL. In an attempt to fix that, one may try this...

```
ErrorDocument 403 https://site.tld/error/script.php
```

But that redirects the client to `https://site.tld/error/script.php` which is UNDESIRED because they have to retype the url, and thus unable to just change the `http` to `https`.

So, I imagine I must do one of the following:

- EXCLUDE `./error` from the SSL requirement with some `.htaccess` handling **OR**
- Build a REWRITE rule that detects the use of an error page, and doesn't rewrite the URL

I was unable to do either of this things yesterday. Perhaps neither of those options are viable, but I'm stuck at what to do.

How can I instruct `.htaccess` to allow `http` connections in `./error`, or some other fix, so I still get my error pages, but the client still keeps their original URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here is my fix for now.

I have a folder structure as follows:

```
/ (web root)
|
|- .htaccess
|- index.php
|
|- error
|- dir1
|- dir2
~
|- dir(n - 1)
`- dir(n)
```

In (web root).htaccess I have the following:

```
Options -Indexes

ErrorDocument 403 /error/script.php
```

And within ANY subdir's folder (EXCEPT FOR /error/):

```
SSLOptions +StrictRequire
SSLRequireSSL
```

This allows me to load error pages without SSL, but still enforce it for every other folder. Is it pretty? No, I'd like to be able to control this from the root's .htaccess. But this is the only thing I have gotten to work so far.

If you can find a better solution, please post your work here.